# SQLite Administration Tool with System.Data.SQLite encryption support

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Is there any SQLite Administration Tool which provides System.Data.SQLite encryption support other than SQLite Expert Professional?

I'm asking this because the SQLite Expert Professional app throws errors when trying to create foreign keys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try [DataDevelop](http://datadevelop.codeplex.com/) it uses the current [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/) library that supports encryption via Password either in clear-text or binary.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager - it's free and works for my system.data.sqlite encrypted databases (pick 'Compatible with ADO.NET provider' when entering db key)
http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/

My manager of choice is the FireFox SQLite Manager extension, but this doesn't support encryption yet...

Comment: Thank you Jim for the answer. I have tried SQLite 2009 Pro Enterprise Manager and it is not compatible with the encryption within the latest System.Data.SQLite that I'm using (1.0.94). It always throws the "file is encrypted or not a database" error.

Comment: It does that with me too - I click OK then it brings up a window allowing me to type in the encryption key and select the type (ADO.NET provider seems to work)

Comment: As of 2020 it looks dead as a doornail.

Answer (score 1):

https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt?act=download

i have found this one really helpful as well as free and very very convinient...